# Want Common Nginx configuration on top of all Nginx configs

Tags: nginx, server, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have a server where nearly 50 different websites are hosted.
Each of them has a separate Nginx config file all of them are listening on port 443 with a different `server_name` and I want to block a certain `location` for all websites.

Is there a way that I can add a rule in `nginx.conf` which is being applied for all the websites, like a parent rule? I tried listening on 443 in `nginx.conf` without any `server_name` and set the `location` and denying the request, but it blocked all the other configs.

Please suggest a solution such that I can block the `.git` folder and all paths starting with dot to be blocked by Nginx for all website instead of changing in each and every config file.

Comment: No. The simplest solution would be an `include` file, that is included into every `server` block.

Comment: I want a parent Nginx conf file that will be applied for every config first, as changing in each and every file is very tedious.

Comment: @aRvi it's very tedious already if you have to manage 50 websites' alone. The answer is `ansible`.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin can you please provide a solution or a link